# Python3 -m venv returns error

Tags: 14.04, python3, virtualenv

I have Ubuntu 14.04 lts and python3.6.4 installed and when I enter like it's said here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

```
python3 -m venv env
```

to create my virtual environment I get the error:

```
Error: Command '['/home/azat/PycharmProjects/test/playground/myvenv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Tell me please how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't get any answer I've found a solution. Maybe it'll help someone out.

I have reinstalled Python 3.6.4 to the system.

And then I have created the virtual env in this way:

```
    python3.6 -m venv myvenv
```

And it's worked for me. I didn't see such solution anywhere while googling. It was said everywhere that it's a bug of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS itself and several workarounds were suggested but nothing has worked for me except the above following.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the python version explicitly resolved the issue:
python3 -m venv venv #did not work
python3.11 -m venv venv #works!
##Note python3 links to python3.11, but some other link seems not to be there.